# Retina Graphics displaying too big?

Tags: css, media-queries, retina-display, retina

I have made two images: one for normal display (350px x 43px), and the other for retina (700px x 86px). Using the code below everything works as it is supposed to regarding changing the images out but hi-res.jpg is being displayed at his actual size of 700px x 86px? I am totally new to retina graphics and therefore have no idea the correct way to fix this. Both images should be inside of a div that is 350px wide and 43px high!

I thought what was happening is that on a retina display there are so many more pixels per inch and a larger image is therefore needed. I have made a larger image but how do I contain it inside a div and get it to display properly?

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5){
    .retina-logo{
        display: block;
        text-align: center; 
        max-height: 43px; 
        max-width: 350px; 
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="logo"><img src="elements/logo.jpg"></img></div>
<div class="retina-logo"><img src="elements/hi-res-logo.jpg"></img></div>
```

Thank you very much for any help. I have been trying all sorts of css to fix this!

Comment: Can you add the CSS for the normal sized image?

Comment: Are you turning off the normal sized img? Or are they both displaying?

Comment: hi-res-logo.jpg is displaying when I open the site on an ipad. It is exceeding it's div though! It is turned off via display: none;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I always do is add height="..." and then the height value of the smallest size

Example:
You want an image of 400px x 400px;

Create & use file at double size (800px)
Then do something like this:

< img src="./img/pathto/.jpg" height="400">

I have a Macbook Pro Retina and this method works great.
You could also use the @2x javascript (Google it).
This automatically switches to the right image.

Hope this will help.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you very much for your help, I now have a nice looking logo on my ipad instead of a pixelated one!

Answer (score 1):

Your div is the right size for the image, but you also need to set a height & width for the image itself. Images don't scale by default.
Try something like this:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5){
    .retina-logo{
        display: block;
        text-align: center; 
        max-height: 43px; 
        max-width: 350px; 
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
    .retina-logo img{
       width: 100%;
       height: auto;
    }
}
```